# Making center tapped transformer to non center tapped?

Tags: transformer

[image: Picture of the transformer]

I have center tapped transformer 12-CT-12 that looks like this picture.

I want to know if I can make this transformer to non-CT transformer with both output of 12V shorted together so I can use a full bridge rectifier increasing transformer utilization factor (TUF.) Will the center tap will the "0"? See the second picture T2.

[image: Simple Transformer Schematic]

Will it make my transformer go KABOOM??

Comment: You can't short the secondary side of the transformer! You need to know the dot convention of the transformer to tell for sure, but if the dot is on the top for each secondary winding, you need to cut open the CT connection in the middle in order to be able to parallel both 12 V windings. But it begs the question, how come you can't use it in CT configuration with two diodes?

Comment: "or it will make my transformer goes KABOOM??" **yes.**

Comment: @winny so i need to rewinding it or just cut the CT connection? i can use it, but i just asking a question

Comment: Not rewind, just cut the connection. It's usually terminated on a pin and not buried inside the windings.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the centre tap, just ignore it. You will have a 24V transformer.  There's no need to cut anything.

What you can't do is short the ends of the transformer together. The AC outputs are out of phase with each other. It will go bang if you do that.

What you can do is put a single diode on each end of the transformer, then use the centre tap as the 0V. It gives the same result as a bridge rectifier, with only 2 diodes.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it make my transformer go KABOOM??

For sure!!

Here's a combination of 'full-bridge' and 'half-bridge with centre tap' configurations.

[image]

The output voltages would be as shown, considering forward voltage drop per diode as 1 V.